# Datatable Collapsible RowGroup with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

I am not very familiar with datatables. In fact, I have just been learning out to use it for the past couple of weeks.
I have a requirement to develop a datatable with collapsible\expandable rowgroups with checkboxes.

The following example achieves what I need except rowgroups (or headers showing the total number of lines under each city) are not collapsible\expandable.

https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/2b0revo8/

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/objects.json',
      'orderFixed': [3, 'asc'],
      'rowGroup': {
         'dataSrc': 'office',
         'startRender': function(rows, group) {
            // Assign class name to all child rows
            var groupName = 'group-' + group.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
            var rowNodes = rows.nodes();
            rowNodes.to$().addClass(groupName);
            
            // Get selected checkboxes
            var checkboxesSelected = $('.dt-checkboxes:checked', rowNodes);
            
            // Parent checkbox is selected when all child checkboxes are selected
            var isSelected = (checkboxesSelected.length == rowNodes.length);
            
            return '<label><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkbox" data-group-name="' 
                   + groupName + '"' + (isSelected ? ' checked' : '') +'> ' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</label>';
         }         
      },
      'columns': [
         {
            'data': 'id',
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true
            }
         },
         { 'data': 'name' },
         { 'data': 'position' },
         { 'data': 'office' },
         { 'data': 'salary' }
      ],
      'select': {
         'style': 'multi'
      },
      'order': [[2, 'asc']]
   } );
     
   // Handle click event on group checkbox
   $('#example').on('click', '.group-checkbox', function(e){
      // Get group class name
      var groupName = $(this).data('group-name');
      
      // Select all child rows
      table.cells('tr.' + groupName, 0).checkboxes.select(this.checked);
   });

   // Handle click event on "Select all" checkbox
   $('#example').on('click', 'thead .dt-checkboxes-select-all', function(e){
      var $selectAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]', this);      
      setTimeout(function(){
         // Select group checkbox based on "Select all" checkbox state
         $('.group-checkbox').prop('checked', $selectAll.prop('checked'));
      }, 0);
   });     

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/rg-1.0.2/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/rg-1.0.2/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">jQuery DataTables Checkboxes:</a> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/rowgroup/">RowGroup</a></h3>
    
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th></th>        
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>

<hr><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/rowgroup//">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
```

It would be ideal if the rowgroups were collapsed on page load. It should also be possible to expand several rowgroups simultaneaously.

Any idea how to achieve it please?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call toggle event on tr click and need to apply collapse on group or tr
here I updated your code for the collapse group of tr

```
 $('#example').on('click', '.group-checkbox', function(e){
      // Get group class name
      var groupName = $(this).data('group-name');
        var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[groupName];
        collapsedGroups[groupName] = !collapsedGroups[groupName];
      // Select all child rows
      table.cells('tr.' + groupName, 0).checkboxes.select(this.checked)
      $(this).toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
        table.draw(false);
   });
```

here is a working demo if need anything to update you can ask me to hope it may help to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 var collapsedGroups = {};
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/objects.json',
      'orderFixed': [3, 'asc'],
      'rowGroup': {
         'dataSrc': 'office',
         'startRender': function(rows, group) {
            // Assign class name to all child rows
            var groupName = 'group-' + group.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
             var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[groupName];
            var rowNodes = rows.nodes();
            rowNodes.to$().addClass(groupName);
            rowNodes.each(function (r) {
                r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
            });    
            // Get selected checkboxes
            var checkboxesSelected = $('.dt-checkboxes:checked', rowNodes);
            // Parent checkbox is selected when all child checkboxes are selected
            var isSelected = (checkboxesSelected.length == rowNodes.length);
            // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
            return $('<tr/>')
                .append('<td colspan="8"><label><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkbox" data-group-name="' 
                   + groupName + '"' + (isSelected ? ' checked' : '') +'> ' + groupName + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</label></td>')
                .attr('data-name', groupName)
                .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
         
         }         
      },
      'columns': [
         {
            'data': 'id',
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true
            }
         },
         { 'data': 'name' },
         { 'data': 'position' },
         { 'data': 'office' },
         { 'data': 'salary' }
      ],
      'select': {
         'style': 'multi'
      },
      'order': [[2, 'asc']]
   } );
     
   // Handle click event on group checkbox
   $('#example').on('click', '.group-checkbox', function(e){
      // Get group class name
      var groupName = $(this).data('group-name');
        var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[groupName];
        collapsedGroups[groupName] = !collapsedGroups[groupName];
      // Select all child rows
      table.cells('tr.' + groupName, 0).checkboxes.select(this.checked)
      $(this).toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
        table.draw(false);
   });

   // Handle click event on "Select all" checkbox
   $('#example').on('click', 'thead .dt-checkboxes-select-all', function(e){
      var $selectAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]', this);      
      setTimeout(function(){
         // Select group checkbox based on "Select all" checkbox state
         $('.group-checkbox').prop('checked', $selectAll.prop('checked'));
      }, 0);
   });     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/rg-1.0.2/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/rg-1.0.2/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">jQuery DataTables Checkboxes:</a> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/rowgroup/">RowGroup</a></h3>
    
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th></th>        
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>

<hr><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/rowgroup//">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
```

Comment: This is great and useful. It gets me close to the desired result. I have lost the ability to select all child rows by clicking on the checkbox in the header row. Perhaps, it would be useful to add + and - buttons next to the header's checkbox which will allow the group to be expanded or collapsed. Or even a Expand\Collapse button on top of the table to expand or collapse all groups at once.

Comment: thanks @Rod you can do that or need any help?